# Is it possible in JProfiler 9.2 (or later) to ignore methods with the same signature in any class matching a pattern?

Tags: java, methods, jprofiler

As the title suggests: Can one ignore methods with the same signature in different classes matching a pattern?

I'd like to ignore `hashCode` and `equals` by default to prevent hotspots from being instrumented.

If it is possible, how would one configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as of JProfiler 10.1, but it will be implemented in JProfiler 11, where you will be able to specify `*` for the class in the list of ignore methods.

Comment: Thx. I'm about to accpet your answer, but still I have to ask: Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: I'm the one who will develop this feature :-)

Comment: It just hit me that if one can ignore/exclude methods in classes via a pattern, one should also be able to include those methods in other classes. Much like the "Define Filters" feature for packages. The reason is of course that one should be able to profile methods such as `hashCode` and `equals` for some classes but ignore them for the rest. I'm pretty sure you figured as much, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to let you know. Thank you for your time. :)